# Permalinks in Wordpress not working with Laravel + Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, nginx

I have a site developed with Laravel on my main route say `www.example.com/`. I have configured it properly with Nginx and php-fpm. My config is below.

Then I added a blog in route `/blog` (`www.example.com/blog/`) and configured it with Nginx `alias`.

Now the problem is that Permalinks in Wordpress are not working. Nginx redirects to Laravel's 404 page.

For example when user enters some URL like this: `example.com/blog/about`, Laravel's 404 page shows up which is weird.

How can I fix this? How can I config Nginx? What's Wrong?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        alias /usr/share/nginx/blog/;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   /usr/share/nginx$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/main_site;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use `alias` when the `location` matches the end of the alias path. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

The `try_files` in `location /blog` needs to default to the WordPress router (`/blog/index.php`) and not the Laravel router (`/index.php`).

Try:

```
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    root /usr/share/nginx;
    ...

    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works now. I used `try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;` with `alias`. It didn't work. But when removed alias it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are running laravel on your server and you want to use wordpress as a blog. and you installed wordpress in blogs named folder. Then you have to do changes in 3 places

```
1) laravel .htaccess file
2) blogs folder .htaccess file
3) nginx configuration file
```

1. Laravel.htaccess file changes add this line

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blogs/
2. blogs folder .htaccess file add this code or modify

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /blogs/   # <==== CHANGED LINE!!
   RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /blogs/index.php [L] # <==== CHANGED LINE!!!
3. in nginx configuration file try modify below code in both port 80 and port 443 code block

   ```
    location /blogs {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blogs/index.php?$args;
    set                     $base /var/www/html;
    root                    $base/public;



    location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi..

    }
   ```

   }